# Do convergence a.e. + limit function being in $L^p$ imply $L^p$ convergence?

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis

Suppose $f_n\in L^p$ such that $f_n \to f$ almost everywhere.

If we further know $f \in L^p$, can we say that $f_n \to f$ in $L^p$ norm?

Comment: No, $f_n = \chi_{[n,n+1]}$ for example.

Comment: In general, no. Consider $f_n = n^{1/p}\cdot \chi_{[0,1/n]}$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Nice counter-example for the second question. Unfortunately the OP deleted the comment. Could you undelete it so your comment remains clear?

Comment: @AlexR I deleted my question since I wanted to think about it a little bit. But, here was my second question: if we further know that $f_n \to f$ in $L^1$ norm, then do we have $f_n \to f$ in $L^p$?

Comment: @DanielFischer I deleted my question since I wanted to think about it a little bit. But, here was my second question: if we further know that $f_n \to f$ in $L^1$ norm, then do we have $f_n \to f$ in $L^p$?

Comment: For the second question the answer is NO. For example, for  $ p=2$ : Let $f_n(x)= \sqrt n$  for $ x \in (0,1/n)$ ,  and $f_n(x)=0 $ , else

Comment: @user254665 That's the $p=2$ case of Daniel Fischers' general example.

Comment: @hl0202 Assuming a finite measure space, if $f_n\to f$ a.e. *and* $\|f_n\|_p\le C$ then $f_n\to f$ in $L^1$ by [Vitali convergence theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vitali_convergence_theorem) (easy to see that $\|f_n\|_p\le C$ implies uniform integrability). So in the sense, $L^1$ convergence is quite weak for the purpose. For $L^p$ convergence you would need convergence $\|f_n\|_p\to\|f\|_p$ instead of boundedness.

Comment: Here is a very good reference about the connection between a.e convergence and $L^p$ convergence. There are 3 theorems, that are worth reading : http://www.jstor.org/stable/2319009?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents

Comment: @Svetoslav Thx. I will take a look

Answer (score 1):

#### Counterexamples

No, $f_n = \chi_{[n,n+1]}$ for example (on $\mathbb{R}$). For an example  on a finite measure space (such as $[0,1]$), consider $f_n = n^{1/p}\cdot \chi_{[0,1/n]}$. -- [Daniel Fischer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1406066/do-convergence-a-e-limit-function-being-in-lp-imply-lp-convergence#comment2864061_1406066)

#### Additional remark

Assuming a finite measure space, if $f_n\to f$ a.e. *and* $\|f_n\|_p\le C$ then $f_n\to f$ in $L^1$ by [Vitali convergence theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vitali_convergence_theorem) (easy to see that $\|f_n\|_p\le C$ implies uniform integrability). So in the sense, $L^1$ convergence is quite weak for the purpose. For $L^p$ convergence you would need convergence $\|f_n\|_p\to\|f\|_p$ instead of boundedness. -- [A.G.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1406066/do-convergence-a-e-limit-function-being-in-lp-imply-lp-convergence#comment2864614_1406066)